# Erlang - A function that returns how many of its 3 arguments are equal

Tags: erlang

I'm just starting on erlang and I have this class task to create a function that returns how many of its 3 arguments are equal. Example:

- countDuplicates(1,2,3) = 0
- countDuplicates(1,2,2) = 2
- countDuplicates(2,2,2) = 3

My solution to this is:

```
- module(equals).
- export([Duplicates/3]).


Duplicates(X,Y,Z)-> 
   List=[X,Y,Z],
   A=length(List),

   List2=lists:usort(List),
   B=length(List2),


if
   A-B==0 ->
      0;
   true ->
   A-B+1   
end.
```

The code takes the arguments as a list then creates another list2 by remove any duplicates using usort.

- A= length of list
- B= length of list2

A-B+1= number of duplicates.
If A-B is 0 then stay 0.

This is my newbie way of solving this problem. What is the most elegant way of doing this?

Comment: No function can be called `Duplicates` with the leading capital D.

Comment: Is the first case 0, or 1? :)

Comment: You need to work on your indenting, which should be 4 spaces--not 3 spaces. And an if expression inside the body of a function needs to be indented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My newbie way would be

```
countDuplicates(X, Y, Z) ->
    if
        X == Y andalso Y == Z ->
            3;
        X /= Y andalso Y /= Z andalso Z /= X ->
            0;
        true -> 2
    end.
```

Comment: In erlang, the recommended style for function names is snake_case: `count_duplicates`.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use pattern matching in the head of the duplicates function:

```
-module(my).
-compile(export_all).

duplicates(N, N, N) -> 3;
duplicates(N, N, _) -> 2;
duplicates(N, _, N) -> 2;
duplicates(_, N, N) -> 2;
duplicates(_, _, _) -> 0.

duplicates_test() ->
    0 = duplicates(1,2,3),
    2 = duplicates(1,2,2), 
    2 = duplicates(2,2,1),
    2 = duplicates(2,1,2),
    3 = duplicates(2,2,2),
    all_tests_passed.
```

In the shell:

```
~/erlang_programs$ erl
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
Eshell V9.3  (abort with ^G)

1> c(my).               
my.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,my}

2> my:duplicates_test().
all_tests_passed

3>
```

That is the kind of function definition that erlang is known for.